# for (int charcode: message)

Tags: java, char

Allow me to ask a stupid question. I am currently doing my tutorial work but I don't get what the (charcode: message) mean.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int [] message = 
        {82, 96, 103, 103, 27, 95, 106, 105, 96, 28};
        //the secret message 
        final int key = 5;
        //key to unlock the message
        for (int charcode: message){
            System.out.print((char)(charcode + key));

        }
        //termincate with a newline
        System.out.println();

    }
```

Comment: It's shorthand `for(int i=0;i<message.length;i++){int charcode = message[i]; ...}` but actually slightly different (as it uses the Iterator).

Comment: See the [enhanced for loop notation in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=enhanced+for+loop). It is syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 5):

It's called a foreach. It allows you to iterate over every element in the array with ease, the code below would be the 'equivalant':

```
for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++)
    System.out.print((char)(message[i] + key));
```

Or:

```
for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++)
{
    int charcode = message[i];
    System.out.print((char)(charcode + key));
}
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for some more information.

Comment: @MByD: Note that I've put quotes around equivalant. Feel free to edit my answer if you think that it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It is the *enhanced for loop*. In short: it iterates over the `message` array and assigns *the next* value to `charcode` in each iteration.

It's equivalent to

```
for(int $i=0; $i<message.length; $i++) {
  int charcode = message[$i];
  System.out.print((char)(charcode + key));
}
```

(*Note* - it named the counter `$i` just to show, that it is hidden and not usable in the enhanced for loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int charcode: message){
    System.out.print((char)(charcode + key));
}
```

This creates a loop over the items in `message`. Each time through, `charcode` is set to the current element in the array, until all items have been printed. It's called a foreach loop.